# Unable to recover deleted projects in Azure DevOps 2020

Tags: azure-devops

I am unable to recover deleted projects in Azure DevOps Server 2020 On premsie. Do you have any idea?
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can try visiting this project using InPrivate window or on different browsers. If it worked fine in private mode. It was probably caused by corrupted cache data. Then you need to clear your browser data. Clear cookies and local storage ("developer tools/application/clear storage/clear site data"). See [this](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/467173/azure-devops-an-unexpected-error-has-occurred-with-1.html) similar thread for more information.

This error could be caused by some preview features too. If you enabled some preview features. You can try disabling them to see if the error will be gone. See [this thread](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/862866/an-unexpected-error-has-occurred-within-this-regio-15.html) for more information.